# different images for enable and disable states of a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

I want to change the image of the button in the code below based on its state i.e. use different image for enable and disable state.

```
<Button CommandParameter="Open" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image Source="../icons/big/open.png" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a style with triggers like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Name="PART_Image" Source="path to normal image" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="path to mouse over image" TargetName="PART_Image"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="path to pressed image" TargetName="PART_Image"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="path to disabled image" TargetName="PART_Image"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is there no way to use some kind of graying-out filter (and others) to generate the images on the fly? Do we have to have essentially hard-coded images of the different states?

Comment: Yes, you could use the same logic as described above and change the Opacity property of the image.  You could also do things like adding a Border to the template and show/hide it when the mouse is over the image, or change the background color ...

Comment: @MalRoss - Check out this codeproject article, which shows how you can use a value converter to create a disabled image on the fly. I'm with you, that it is frustrating to have to write code to do things that WinForms does for free, but at least you don't have to pre-gen the images. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GrayscaleButton.aspx

Answer (score 9):

I used the following code to make images inside buttons to have half the opacity when the button is disabled and it works great!

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Style.Triggers see post [wpf-style-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321701/wpf-style-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, create a style for the button which makes it display an image object in its content property, and then have a trigger which checks the buttons enabled state, and when it is TRUE have it be one image, and at all other times be the other image.