# how to define parameters for a style in wpf

Tags: wpf, styles

I have severals buttons in my applications and I want to have different images for them for when they are enabled, presses and mouse over. I found this question in this site that show me how to do this for a button.

[different images for enable and disable states of a button in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532125/different-images-for-enable-and-disable-states-of-a-button-in-wpf)

but since I have several buttons on my application it is difficult to write the same code for each of them. Is there a way that I can define a parametrise style so for example I can define each of my butons as follow:

```
 <Button ActiveImage=" active image name" DisableImage="disabled image name" style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

which shorten my xamle?

Comment: you could define several attached properties and bind the properties of template to the attached properties.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please give me some code samples?

Comment: just added example as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this using attached properties. You can define them in a separate class (say, `ButtonHelper`) like it's described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#custom.

Next, you make your style to reference the attached properties:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Name="PART_Image"
                           Source="{Binding (local:ButtonHelper.NormalImageSource),
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                Value="{Binding (local:ButtonHelper.HoverImageSource),
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                TargetName="PART_Image"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!-- and so on -->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

(the code is stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532262/276994)).

Don't forget to declare as `local` the namespace where the `ButtonHelper` class is located!

Comment: Thnaks. Can you please provide more information about the structure of ButtonHelper and also how to define a button on xaml and use the buttonhelper?

Comment: There is an example here: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.de/2010/05/attached-dependency-properties-for.html You just don't need `CallBackWhenPropertyIsChanged` (so it can be omitted inside `new PropertyMetadata`.