# Change Image Source when the Parent Button change its enabled state

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, binding

I have this XAML code:

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonUpdate" IsEnabled="False">
    <Image Source="Images/update gray.png" Name="ImgUpdate" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/update.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

I want that when `ButtonUpdate` is enabled:

```
ButtonUpdate.IsEnabled = true;
```

the `ImgUpdate.Source` become `"Images/update.png"`, and when `ButtonUpdate` is not enabled:

```
ButtonUpdate.IsEnabled = false;
```

the `ImgUpdate.Source` become `"Images/update gray.png"` using data binding.

My XAML code doesn't work. Where is the error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Trigger` applies to the `Image`, not the button, so the `IsEnabled` property that is monitored in this case is the `Image.IsEnabled` property, which is not what you want.

You can either create a `Style` for the `Button` and use a `Trigger` in that `Style` to change the `Content` of the button based on the `IsEnabled` state, or you could create a `ControlTemplate` with the `Image` as the content of the `Button` and change the `Source` of the `Image` based on the enabled state of the button.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532125/different-images-for-enable-and-disable-states-of-a-button-in-wpf) seems to provide  the specifics for what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The image source property should be in this format:

**"/«YourAssemblyName»;component/«YourPath»/«YourImage.png»"**

Example

```
<Image Source="/WPFApplication;component/Images/Start.png" />
```

See this post for more info:

[WPF image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources)