# Difference between Button with Image as ControlTemplate and Image with PointerPressed Event

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

What is the difference between a button with an Image as its ControlTemplate, and an Image with a PointerPressed event handler?

You can set up event handlers for both for when you click on them, so what is the difference, or pros/cons for each?

Here's the Button code:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="pic.jpg"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Here's the Image code:

```
<Image Source="pic.jpg" PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Button has states, whereas an image can have event handlers but was not specifically designed to be an input. See also [different images for enable and disable states of a button in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532125/different-images-for-enable-and-disable-states-of-a-button-in-wpf)